# Different event labels (title) per calendar view

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I display different labels (titles) for events, when switching from week/months/day views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at this topic it has very good code and other members that are trying dodo what you asking here.

[JQuery full calendar, how to change view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637248/jquery-full-calendar-how-to-change-view/5741423#5741423)