# Group same day events

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using JSON for feed and tooltip to show additional information. I want to group all same day events.

For example if there are 3 events for 28th april, there will a single icon in the 28th april block (instead of 3), hovering over it will display additional details for all the three events.

What is the best way to approach this? I want to achieve this in the month view.

Comment: Do you have any influence over what's generating your JSON?

Comment: Have a look here- i already answered this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637248/jquery-full-calendar-how-to-change-view/5741423#5741423

Comment: Yes i do.The JSON feed is generated from php

Comment: In that case, I'd do all the manipulation on your JSON source - i.e. if you have an event on a specific date, generate just one JSON item for it. Then, on hover, have another request to get all events on that date.

Comment: Yes i did try something like that and figured it out.Thank you for your response.