# How to add buttons and links to FullCalendar's cells

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm new to FullCalendar.
In my project, I need to show Calendar with time range and allocated participants for each training center for each day.
To be more precise, a day can have many training slot that will be conducted by training center.
So, I would like to show which training center is allocated to which time ranges and the number of available slot.
Recently, I saw FullCalendar control can show time and events.
For my case, I want to add links(one will go to editing of training slot and another link will go to editing of training participants.)
How can i done this?

with thanks,
Thura

Answer (score 4):

You can add buttons to the calendar; look at this utoob flick

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKUu9KJxunI

That was my calendar and the code and explanation is found here

[JQuery full calendar, how to change view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637248/jquery-full-calendar-how-to-change-view/5741423#5741423)

You will have to insert buttons manually- There is no way of doing it out of the box with fullcalnedar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ppumkin.
I'm now changing fullCalendar into manually created calendar.

Answer (score 1):

```
 eventRender: function (event, element) {
                //element.find('.fc-event-inner').append("<p>" + event.description + "</p>");
                if (event.innerHtml != null)
                    element.find('.fc-event-inner').append(event.innerHtml);

            }
```

and send the innerHtml inside the event object.