# FullCalendar - limiting the scope of

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

how to (what I must to change inside the code) to limit the scope of view (by using the button by users) to view only:

in week view - only the actual week without the way to previous and to next week

in the day view - actual day of course and with a way to view ONLY days from actual week (buttons previous and next).

(in month view - i dont use this view, without the month button (I know how to eliminate the month button))

How to delete buttons (previous/next) from week view?

I want to use only actual week view and the days (in days view) from this actual week.

ps.
maybe it helps - I've two extra variables (from php TimeZone section):

$date1 - it's a first day (date) of the actual week (monday)

$date7 - it's a last day (date) of the actual week (sunday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the previos and next buttons you can use jQueries power to hide elemetns by their class or ID.

```
$('.fc-button-prev, .fc-button-next').hide();
```

and this way you can always re show them, but if you never want to use it, just construct your fulclalendar with the [following methods](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/header/)

```
    header: {
         left: 'today',
         center: 'prev,title,next',
         right: 'month,basicDay'
     },
```

To change dates using a dropdown meneu, populate the select the way you wish, from server php side,

For example my php writes this..(only partial code, but for example)

```
"<option <?php echo 'value=\'' . $date1 . '\'>' . $date1; ?> - Monday</option>" +
```

The resulting HTML should look like this

```
<option value="2012-02-27">2012-02-27 - Monday</option>
```

then again use the power of jQuery...

```
        $('#myDateSelector').change(function() {
            var selectedText = $('#myDateSelector option:selected').text(); //Gets the TEXT
            var selectedValue = $('#myDateSelector option:selected').val(); //gets the Value='abc'

            var selectedDate = new Date(selectedValue);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',selectedDate);
        } );
```

[Another answer of mine show more complex code on how to control fullcalendar, but it uses ASP server tags not PHP.. the JavaScript is still the same logic though.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741423/706363)